# Script runs in Windows but fails in Jenkins

Tags: bash, ant

I have a bash script :

```
C:/Jenkins/workspace/xmlstarlet-1.6.1-win32/xmlstarlet-1.6.1/xml.exe ed -L -s "/Package/types[name='$TYPENAME']" -t elem -n members -v "$ENTITY" $SCRIPTFILE

C:/Jenkins/workspace/xmlstarlet-1.6.1-win32/xmlstarlet-1.6.1/xml.exe ed -L -s "/Package" -t elem -n types -v "" $SCRIPTFILE
```

which inserts node for a particular type in an xml, this runs fine in local, but when trying to run via any script it fails:

Ant script:

```
    <exec executable="C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" osfamily="windows">
        <arg value="generate_package.sh" />
        <arg value="C:/Jenkins/workspace/TrailheadBranchDemo/final.txt" />
        <arg value="package" />
        <arg value="C:/Jenkins/workspace/deploy/src" />
    </exec>
```

Error message : 
    Invalid expression: C:/Program Files/Git/Package

It is not able to pick the `/Package` or `/Package/types[not(*)]` expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is :

on windows the bash script works like this:

```
$ C:/Jenkins/workspace/xmlstarlet/xmlstarlet/xml.exe ed -L -i "Package" -t attr -n xmlns -v "http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" C:/Jenkins/workspace/deploy/src/package.xml
```

instead of this :

```
$ C:/Jenkins/workspace/xmlstarlet/xmlstarlet/xml.exe ed -L -i '/Package' -t attr -n xmlns -v "http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" C:/Jenkins/workspace/deploy/src/package.xml
```

the `/Package` is not recognized well in windows.